# Redirect all pages to a sub directory of the website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Is it possible to redirect all pages of a website to a sub directory of that website, keeping original URL at the end of the redirected URL?

Something like:

```
www.example.com/hello-word -> www.example.com/blog/hello-world
```

Or in other words, a wildcard redirect to a sub folder, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following rules inside the `.htaccess` file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect urls that do not contain path
RewriteRule ^$ /blog/ [R,L]
# Redirect urls that do not map to a directory and file, and do not begin with /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!blog/)(.*) /blog/$1 [R,L]
```

If necessary, replace `R` with `R=301` after testing your rules thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/?$ http://example.com/blog/$1
```

http://www.example.com/anything would redirect to http://www.example.com/blog/anything

Comment: That means any characters the pattern matches,